# Apache Digester: NoSuchMethodException: no such accesible method

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, apache-commons-digester

I have a problem with Apache Digester because it's calling **set method** on the **current object** instead of in the **object that corresponds to parent tag**. The result is a NoSuchMethodException.

`Note: I'm reusing the Digester object due to performance problems, but I'm calling clear() method before each parse.`

Here is my code: (It is **calling setHeader** method **on Header object** instead of **Message object**).

The XML:

```
<message>
    <header id_message="2014871" date="07/08/2014 21:56:41" />
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</message>
```

And the code to create the digester:

```
digesterSOBB = new Digester();
digesterSOBB.setValidating(true);
digesterSOBB.setSchema(XMLParser.class.getResource(dtdUrlSOBB).getFile());
digesterSOBB.register("message", XMLParser.class.getResource(dtdUrlSOBB));
digesterSOBB.setErrorHandler(new XMLDtdValidationErrorHandler());

//Message
digesterSOBB.addObjectCreate("message", "com.company.utils.xmlparser.beans.sosc.Message");
digesterSOBB.addSetProperties("message");

//Header-I
digesterSOBB.addObjectCreate("message/header", "com.company.utils.xmlparser.beans.sosc.Header"); 
digesterSOBB.addSetProperties("message/header");
digesterSOBB.addSetNext("message/header", "setHeader", "com.company.utils.xmlparser.beans.sosc.Header");
```

It is working properly but, when it process some xmls, it try to call setHeader method in Header object:

```
[8/7/14 5:22:00:322 CEST] 00000061 Digester      E org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger error End event threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible method: setHeader() on object: com.company.utils.xmlparser.Header
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:278)
at org.apache.commons.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:217)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:253)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1332)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
...
```

I've reviewed the javadoc (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/commons-digester-2.0/docs/api/), and the code seems to be ok (the second parameter is the method name to call on the parent element):

```
public void addSetNext(String pattern,
                       String methodName,
                       String paramType)
Add a "set next" rule for the specified parameters.
Parameters:
pattern - Element matching pattern
methodName - Method name to call on the parent element
paramType - Java class name of the expected parameter type (if you wish to use a primitive type, specify the corresonding Java wrapper class instead, such as java.lang.Boolean for a boolean parameter)
```

Comment: The stacktrace mentions `org.company.utils.xmlparser.Header`, but your digister configuration says `"com.company.utils.xmlparser.beans.sosc.Header"`. Is it mistake?

Comment: It was my fault, I've already edited and corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this library, but looking over the manual, it is stack based - is there an ordering issue when referring to the parent (Message) which presumably is under the child (Header), the newer object being on top of the stack?

The FAQ has a little information about this:
http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Digester/FAQ

See -> *How do I get CallMethodRule to fire before SetNextRule?*
Where the suggested example sequence is:

```
digester.addObjectCreate("parent", Parent.class);
digester.addObjectCreate("parent/child", Child.class);
digester.addSetNext("parent/child", "addChild");
digester.addCallMethod("parent/child", "setName", 1);
digester.addCallParam("parent/child/name", 0);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it should not be the problem because I'm using SetPropertiesRule and at the end it says: "Note that this problem does *not* occur when using the SetPropertiesRule. This rule does all its work when the matching start tag is encountered (because it only requires the attributes which are all present on the start tag) and so does not experience the "reverse call" order that applies to the "end" method of Rules."  :(.

Comment: Anyway I'm going to review the code because I'm using addCallMethod to parse inner tags. May be that this is causing the failure.